# How to trigger close modal in Chakra UI?

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I am using Modal Component in Chakra UI to show Input editor post (Input editor is a children component wrapped by Modal component). I want to trigger close modal from Input editor component if data was fetched as succeed.

Here's my component for Modal:

```
//...import component from Chakra Modal
import {Post as PostModal} from '../components/Modal'

export const Post = () => {

  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure()

  return (
    <div>
  <Modal onClose={onClose} size='full' isOpen={isOpen} trapFocus={false} >
    <ModalOverlay />
    <ModalContent>
      <ModalHeader>Add Post</ModalHeader>
      <ModalCloseButton />
      <ModalBody>
        <div>
          <PostModal />
        </div>
      </ModalBody>
    </ModalContent>
  </Modal>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And my code handle fetcher post data:

```
/components/Modal

const fetcher = async (data) => {
  const _ = await sendPost(data);
  if (_) {
    //here i want to trigger close modal
  }
}

const PostInput = () => {
  return (
    //<Input/>
    //<Textarea> etc...
  )
}
```

Who can help me please?

Comment: Please include the code of modal declaration

Comment: @NeERAJTK Please help me, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the `onClose` function once the API call is successful , as:

```
const fetcher = async (data) => {
  let res = await sendPost(data);
  if (res.data) {
    onClose()
  }
}
```

Comment: it didn't work for me.

Comment: Its working for me! https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-with-different-content-forked-1i22e?file=/src/MyModal.js . Press the Get data button after opening the modal.